# Not receiving response errors from Backend RestAPI using Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I am having trouble receiving a response from my backend (Node.js Express RestAPI).

```
exports.send = function(req, res) {
    console.log("sent function running!")
    let contact = new Contact(req.body)
    contact.send()
    if (contact.errors.length) {
        res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify(contact.errors));
        return;
    }
    res.send("Message Sent!")
}
```

The above will send the errors that were encountered via res.status(400) line.

When I use PostMan to send a POST method I receive the correct response messages. see below.

[image]

However when I use Axios on my frontend I am not receiving a response

**FrontEnd**

```
const axios = require('axios')


class ContactForm {
    constructor() {
        this.name = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        this.email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        this.message = document.getElementById("message").value;
        this.submitButton = document.getElementById("submitMessage")
        this.events();
    }

    events() {
        this.submitButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => this.sendMesage(e))
    }

    sendMesage(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/contact/send', {
            name: this.name,
            email: this.email,
            message: this.message
        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res)
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log("ran into errors")
            console.log(e)
        })

    }

}

export default ContactForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the catch block, try this:

```
  .catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error.response.data);
  });
```

I tested it on my browser, it gives me the error message:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `console.log(e.message)` to get the response message.

Comment: just says "Request failed with status code 400"

Comment: Hm. Perhaps you need to parse the response to use it. How about `e.json()`?